# Getting a secure timestamp that cannot be spoofed

Tags: security, timestamp, certificate

What is the best approach to fetching a certified time stamp from the internet from within my app?

I have a licence file that expires at a regular period and I must make sure that the certificate is not expired.

Is such a thing even possible/ does it exist? Ideally when my app runs, it should get a secured/certified time stamp representing current time, but I want to make sure it cannot be faked by the application runner.

Are there any services that offer this out there? It can be commercial, I just don't know where to start and am looking for some pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at Timestamping protocol (RFC 3161). It gives you secure time. To properly use the protocol you can ask the server timestamp some random hash (the server doesn't care), then validate the timestamp and if it's ok, use the time in the timestamp. That would be the most effective approach.

There was a TSP client available in BouncyCastle, if memory serves, and our SecureBlackbox product (including free [CryptoBlackbox](https://www.eldos.com/sbb/desc-cryptobb.php) package) also includes a TSP client and powerful validation mechanisms.